# Remove a node from the active Firefox DOM

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

So I am trying to remove browser side input validation on [this](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation$samples/Customized_error_messages) sample page. Firefox inspector console shows the event listener on this field. The listener can easily be tracked. The script node can easily be removed. However, the validation still occurs. So, when I delete the script node, does it not get deleted from the active DOM? How do I remove the node from the active DOM so changes are immediately in effect?

Answer (score 0):

`novalidate` will disable HTML5 validation for you.

```
<form novalidate>
  <label for="mail">I would like you to provide me an e-mail</label>
  <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am looking to modify the actively loaded DOM.

Comment: you can modify the form element and add the novalidate attribute to it: `document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].setAttribute('novalidate','novalidate')`

Comment: novalidate will not change any custom validation via event handlers.